# Suddenly Android Wearable doesn't show notification anymore?

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, wear-os, wearables

for my app I use a service that implements SensorEventListener. The service collects sensor data from the wearable. In this service I start a notification. Last week, when I tested my App, everything worked fine. But suddenly my wearable doesn't show the notification while my service is in foreground.  Even the older versions of my app don't show the notification anymore. This is very confusing. So, to solve the problem did this:

1. I tested if my service is really in foreground: yes, it really is. On the 
   console I also can see that the watch really is collecting data, so the 
   service does its job.
2. Then I looked through stackoverflow and found that maybe my app got
   muted: I searched for it on my phone, wearable and the Google Wear App, but
   found nothing. So I reseted my watch, took another phone where I installed 
   Google Wear App. After that I paired wearable with phone. Then I deployed 
   my App on the "new" phone and watch: no notification visible. I also 
   changed the application-Id to see if that changes anything: no.
3. I have older versions of my current app, where I'm 100% sure that 
   the notification did show up. I checked them out: the notification is not
   visible anymore.

I don't know what to do. My service starts, it really is in foreground and it doesn't look like the app is muted.

I set the notification in onCreate() of my service:

```
 Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("TestApplication");
    builder.setContentText("Collecting sensor data..");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    startForeground(1, builder.build());
```

And in onCreate() I also check if my service is in foreground. The method that I use to do that is this (it's copy-paste from another stackoverflow code with little changes):

```
private boolean isServiceRunningInForeground(String serviceName){
    boolean serviceRunning = false;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = am.getRunningServices(50);
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = i
                .next();

        if(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceName)){

            if(runningServiceInfo.foreground)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, can you check this [I’m not getting notifications on my watch](https://support.google.com/wearos/answer/6090188?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) guideline?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to create the notification with  Notification.Builder while using SDK Version 26. Didn't know that with SDK 26 I have to use NotificationCompat.Builder with a notification channel.

So, for everyone with the same problem: 
- change your SDK to a lower version or 
- use NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String notificationChannel) instead of Notification.Builder